# File I/O portfolio instructions

Tags: java

So for a [school project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/24jsyaedrlc69px/DataWriter%20Class.docx?dl=0) I have to write a file I/O portfolio.

The goal is to write a multiplication table to a `.txt` file using `PrintWriter`.

I've done part of it, and I'm kind of lost right now. Here is my code so far:

```
package lesson6;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class DataWriter {

//multiplication table
void multi() {
int[][] table = new int[10][10];
    for(int row = 0; row < table.length; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col< table[row].length; col++) {
        table[row][col]= (row+1) * (col+1);
        System.out.print((row+1) + "X" + (col+1) + " = " + table[row][col] + " ");
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.io.File File = new java.io.File("data.txt");

    try {
        System.out.println("Writing to file.");
        File file = new File ("C:/Users/fjldjsafj/workspace/lesson6/data.txt");
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(File);
        p.println();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Sorry, file not found.");

    }
    System.out.println("Finished writing to file.");
    }

}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong because I have no clue what to do now! Sorry if it is hard to read or understand... and any hints for the next steps would be very helpful!

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Step 1: explain to us what you want it to do

Comment: Agreed. Can you explain the problem? Remember if you cant form the steps to resolve the problem in your brain then you will never be able to do it efficiently in code. Start by breaking it down into steps. For example I want to upload a file to drop box. The steps would be broadly take data write to file. Use dropbox API to upload. Programming is not about writing code it is about solving problems.

Comment: Looks like the assignment is in the dropbox link.  @Joy, can you add to your post which part you are stuck with?

Comment: What is a 'file I/O portfolio'?

Comment: ive gotten to the part "Add a System.out.println() statement that displays the text, "Writing to file." This statement will provide
visual output in Eclipse so that you can see that the program is actually running. " and i dont have any clue what to do for the next steps. any hints for the next steps? they dont have to be exact answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn more about the class [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) from the Java documentation.

Since you are trying to write a multiplication table to a `.txt` file, then you should open an output stream.

Try using something like this:

```
...

String yourFileName = "C:\\yourFileName.txt";
PrintWriter outputStream = null;
try
{
    outputStream = new PrintWriter(yourFileName);
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    System.out.println("Sorry, file not found.");
}
```

Then add your code to try writing to the file.  Make sure you test it.

Afterwards, it is important to close the output stream when you are done writing to the file:

`outputStream.close();`

Hope this helps.